# Refreshing a document library using the client side UI in 2010

Tags: client-object-model, refresh, document-library

After adding a document to a sharepoint document library from an SPModalDialog, how can I refresh the underlying list using the new 2010 client object model in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

There are various approaches to achieve this:

You can use the SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jfrost/how-to-display-a-sharepoint-dialog-from-ribbon-button-and-get-selected-item-context)

OR

In your ribbon button add the following CommandUIHandler :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630938.aspx

OR

Another mrthod is using the SPRibbonPostBackCommand

http://makarandrkulkarni.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-one.html