# Asynchronous postbacks from ribbon controls

Tags: ribbon

I am customizing the ribbon for my share point site to include tabs,controls that are relevant to my application.

I am performing the customization by getting hold of an instance of SPRibbon on a page and calling RegisterDataExtensions() on it. This way I have added ribbon buttons, flyout anchors etc.

However I am facing an issue here.On click of a ribbon button, is it possible to perform partial postback, without having to refresh the entire ribbon?

I did not find any documentation on whether ribbon can be made part of update panel.

Also I tried partial post backs using ICallBackEventHandler, but my understanding is that UI elements cannot be refreshed from server side using this. (Possible only through javascript function, but that option is not very useful in my case).

So how can async operations be triggered from ribbon controls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

see if this is usefull:
[Refreshing a document library using the client side UI in 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6386/refreshing-a-document-library-using-the-client-side-ui-in-2010/6391#6391)